# Lagrange mean value theorem on ramified function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[-2,5]\to\mathbb{R},f(x)= \left\{\begin{array}{l}\sqrt{x+3},\;x\in\lbrack-2,1)\\\frac{x+7}4,x\in\lbrack1,5\rbrack\end{array}\right.$. Find c for when applying Lagrange's theorem on this function.

Okay, so I just used the definition of the mean value Lagrange's Theorem that says:

$$f'(c)=\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Therefore in our case we have:

$$f'(c) = \frac {f(5)-f(-2)}{5-(-2)} = \frac {3-1}{7}= \frac 27$$

but $$f'(x)= \left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac1{2\sqrt{x+3}},\;x\in\lbrack-2,1)\\\frac14,x\in\lbrack1,5\rbrack\end{array}\right.$$

So I said if the second function is just a constant and it's different from the $f'(c)$ then $c$ should be in the first part of the function.

And we get:

$$2\sqrt{c+3}=\frac 72 \to \sqrt{c+3}=\frac 74 \to c+3=\frac {49}{16}\to c = \frac 1{16}.$$

Did I did it right? And if so, what would've happened if the second part of the function's derivative was not a constant? Then I should have 2 $c$'s?

And what happens when I try to apply this theorem on more complicated functions? and what this theorem really *means*(in a graphic way of looking at things)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is right. It is okay if there exist another $c\in(1,5)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac27$. Because Lagrange mean value theorem did not say that $c$ is unique.

For a geometric interpretation see https://www.math24.net/lagranges-mean-value-theorem/